# Finding Substring in Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

How to find substrings in Bigquery? I couldn't find any function which supports firing queries like 'Substring(Column_Name,3,7)'.
Is there any way out to achieve the same functionality in Bigquery?

Comment: You mean find a substring inside a string or get a substring from a string?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH yourTable AS (
  SELECT 'Finding Substring in Bigquery' AS Column_Name
)
SELECT SUBSTR(Column_Name, 9, 12)
FROM yourTable
```

So [`SUBSTR(value, position [, length])`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#substr) is for you to use

See [`String Functions`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#string-functions) for more

Answer (score 0):

You can use substr
e.g. substr(Column_Name,3,7)