# selecting part of a string based on delimiter, from end of the string

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

So I have a column with names. Examples are the following

Mark (BB)

Andy White (CC)

The outcome I want is:

Mark

Andy White

StandardSQL in BQ does not accept RIGHT so I am struggling in starting a regexp from the end of the string.

I am not sure if trying to catch all what's inside the bracket (and bracket itself) or to try to catch the first space " ".

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

Got an answer:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(column_name, r"([^\(]+)")
```

Just needed to try more with the regular expression.

Comment: You also have the option of using the substr() function, you can check the documentation here https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#substr  .... and here are all the supported string functions at the time of writing https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions

Comment: Hei, in this case would you write the SQL sentence with SUBSTR() that could help me?

Comment: No we are not permitted to provide coding services sorry.. only provide the information needed... but this post might help up   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46209955/finding-substring-in-bigquery